# LastPass import feature does not work, v4.1.62 on Firefox v55.0.2 (64-bit)

Tags: import, lastpass, firefox-extensions

I'm trying to get LastPass to import my passwords in a CSV file exported from Avast Passwords. For some strange reason, the option to import passwords doesn't seem to work. The screenshots below showcase the issue I'm currently having.

[image]
[image]

When I press "Other", nothing happens. I've scoured the Internet for a solution. I do have `BinaryComponent` set to `true`. I have also clicked on the "Firefox Password Manager" option, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's hard to know what the issue is without more information.  It's not clear where the BinaryComponent setting is or why it should be selected.  Parenthetically, I have personally found that the latest LP has a lot of bugs since it was a major release, so reporting this to them via a bug report might be the best option in this case.  Failing that, I would try opening the CSV and trimming out all but a few entries to see if you can find a possible problematic one (unicode characters or commas within your own entries could be causing it to choke, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, that button doesn't work so I found another way to access the Import button:

[image]

I also logged out and logged back in again, that may help.

Comment: Brilliant! Absurd fix, though - one should think Lastpass had gotten notice of this problem by the about 48293453 hits "lastpass firefox import not working" google search produces.